How are wheels constructed?
Here’s a small excerpt from Jesper Carlstrom’s paper on wheel theory. I ask for assistance and clarification about $\sim_{S}$ and $≡_{S}$ and the construction of this structure through them. Break it down, please.
"We indicate briefly what the basic ideas are. Proofs and technical verificationsare postponed to the following sections.The natural way of trying to introduce inverses to all elements of a ring, is tomodify the usual construction of rings of fractions. If $A$ is a commutative ringwith identity, $S$ a multiplicative submonoid of it, then the usual construction is as follows:
Define the relation $\sim_{S}$ on $A × S$ (here the product is taken in thecategory of sets) as
$(x, s) \sim_{S} (x', s') \quad \text{means} \quad \exists s'' \in S : s'' (xs' - x's) = 0$
Then $\sim_{S}$ is an equivalence relation and $A × S/ \sim_{S}$ is a commutative ring with (the class containing $(x, y)$ is denoted by $[x, y]$)
$\begin{align*}
0 &= [0, 1] \\
1 &= [1, 1] \\
[x, s] + [x', s'] &= [xs' + x's, ss'] \\
[x, s][x', s'] &= [xx', ss'].
\end{align*}$
Clearly, $0$ can’t be inverted unless $0 ∈ S$, but if that is the case, then $\sim_{S}$ is the improper relation, so that $A × S/ \sim_{S}$ is trivial. The obvious thing to try is to replace $A × S$ by $A × A$. Considering the multiplicative structure only, $A×S$ is a product of monoids and $\sim_{S}$ a congruencerelation on it. Let $≡_{S}$ be the congruence relation that is generated on the monoid $A × A$ by $\sim_{S}$. Then
$(x, y) \equiv_S (x', y') \iff \exists s, s' \in S : (sx, sy) = (s'x', s'y')$
We define $\odot_S A$ (the wheel of fractions with respect to $S$) as $A \times A / \equiv_S$ with the operations
$
0 = [0, 1]
$
$
1 = [1, 1]
$
$
[x, y] + [x', y'] = [xy' + x'y, yy']
$
$
[x, y][x', y'] = [xx', yy']
$
$
/[x, y] = [y, x].
$"

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What exactly is unclear here?

can u expain how $\sim_{S}$ works there. i mean e.g. $[2,1]$ is eq. $[10, 5]$ so we aint need no $s''$ for $s''(25-101)=0$. but there is no info about that $s''≠0$, so all classes are eq. to each other, the same situation about $≡_{S}$, or I am crazy?
